# i don't know why it says now that it can't find any image, saying "no such file or directory"

Tags: python, python-turtle

I just started to learn python, and I wanted to create a basic program to test my skills, but I found this error that didn't appear before. I don't know what's wrong, it used to work until today.

`

```
import turtle

#Window
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.setup(800, 600)
wn.bgpic("game/sea.gif")
wn.title("TEST")
wn.tracer(0)

#fish.
fish = turtle.Turtle()
turtle.register_shape('game/fish-up.gif')
turtle.register_shape('game/fish-down.gif')
turtle.register_shape('game/fish-left.gif')
turtle.register_shape('game/fish-right.gif')
fish.shape('game/fish-right.gif')
fish.goto(0, 0)
fish.penup()
fish.shapesize(2.5, 2.5)

#Functions
def move_up():
    fish.shape('game/fish-up.gif')
    y = fish.ycor()
    y += 10
    fish.sety(y)

def move_down():
fish.shape('game/fish-down.gif')
    y = fish.ycor()
    y -= 10
    fish.sety(y)

def move_left():
    fish.shape('game/fish-left.gif')
    x = fish.xcor()
    x -= 10
    fish.setx(x)

def move_right():
    fish.shape('game/fish-right.gif')
    x = fish.xcor()
    x += 10
    fish.setx(x)

#Keyboard binding
wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(move_up, "w")
wn.onkeypress(move_down, "s")
wn.onkeypress(move_left, "a")
wn.onkeypress(move_right, "d")

#Main game loop
while True:
    wn.update()

    if fish.ycor() > 280:
        fish.sety(280)

    if fish.ycor() < -280:
        fish.sety(-280)

    if fish.xcor() > 380:
        fish.setx(380)

    if fish.xcor() < -380:
        fish.setx(-380)
```

`

In my folder I have four different images for the fish, and one for the background.

It says:

```
 File "c:\Users\USER\Desktop\PYTHON\game\game.py", line 6, in <module>
    wn.bgpic("game/sea.gif")
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\turtle.py", line 1481, in bgpic
    self._bgpics[picname] = self._image(picname)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\turtle.py", line 478, in _image
    return TK.PhotoImage(file=filename, master=self.cv)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4103, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4048, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "game/sea.gif": no such file or directory
```

I tried using \ instead of / and using another directory for the images

Comment: The paths you list are relative to the directory that you run your application from (the **Working Directory**). So most likely those paths don't make sense from wherever you are running from.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.